# get GPS meta from photo

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, ios7.1

General picture is bring up the information well. 
But there is no gps information on pictures in the filter is applied. 
Is there a way to fix?

```
- (void)getGPSLocation : (ALAsset*)asset
{
    NSMutableDictionary *imageMetadata = nil;
    NSDictionary *metadata = asset.defaultRepresentation.metadata;
    imageMetadata = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:metadata];

    latitude = [[[imageMetadata objectForKey:@"{GPS}"]objectForKey:@"Latitude"]doubleValue];
    longitude = [[[imageMetadata objectForKey:@"{GPS}"]objectForKey:@"Longitude"]doubleValue];

    CLGeocoder *ceo = [[CLGeocoder alloc]init];
    CLLocation *loc = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:latitude longitude:longitude]; //insert your coordinates

    addr = [NSString alloc];

    [ceo reverseGeocodeLocation: loc completionHandler:
     ^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {

         CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];

         NSString *locatedAt = [[placemark.addressDictionary valueForKey:@"FormattedAddressLines"] componentsJoinedByString:@", "];

         NSLog(@"I am currently at %@",locatedAt);
         addr = locatedAt;
         //         [_address setText:locatedAt];
         //         [self setPin:latitude longitude:longitude addr:addr];
     }];
}
```

Comment: What I understand from your question is that you are trying to use an image which have no location data attached to it, right ?

Comment: Is accurate. If using a filter to take a picture in basic camera app.

Comment: You probably have tried this but just to confirm, have you tried same code for image without any filter and also made sure location services for camera were on in the device settings ? Settings -> Privacy -> Location services

Comment: np, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
CLLocation *location = [asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyLocation];

latitude = (double)location.coordinate.latitude;
longitude = (double)location.coordinate.longitude;
```

solved.